# Does Tireless Logic work on a concentration check?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Can [Tireless Logic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/social-traits/tireless-logic) be used to reroll a [Concentration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Concentration) check for a caster that uses INT for casting, such as an [Arcanist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/arcanist)?

I believe concentration qualifies as an ability check, but I'm not entirely certain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The benefit of the trait [Tireless Logic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/social-traits/tireless-logic) can't be applied to concentration checks. While the benefit of Tireless Logic does says it allows rerolling a skill check or an ability check, a concentration check is neither. [While the phrase *ability check* isn't defined clearly by the rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills#TOC-Ability-Checks-and-Caster-Level-Checks1), an ability check is different *enough* from a concentration check (and from a caster level check) that, for example, a creature can take 10 on an ability check and can't take 10 on a concentration check (*et al.*). Further, part of *one sentence* says, that a "character rarely rolls an ability check (using *just* an ability score)" (emphasis mine) (paraphrased [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores) but verbatim from *Pathfinder Core Rulebook* 15), making concentration checks ineligible.

However, *Pathfinder*'s antecedent *D&D 3.5* provides a clear definition of [ability check](http://dndsrd.net/skills.html#ability-checks): "An ability check is a roll of 1d20 plus the appropriate ability modifier" (*Player's Handbook* 66). It's unlikely Paizo expanded this definition to include concentration checks, which are the creature's key ability *plus* the creature's caster level.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly no-

Tireless logic states:Once per day when you make an Intelligence-based skill check or ability check, you can roll twice and take the better result.

Seeing as concentration isn't a skill, the only way this could work would be if it were an ability check, but

Ability Checks and Caster Level Checks

The normal take 10 and take 20 rules apply for ability checks. Neither rule applies to concentration checks or caster level checks. - http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills

According to the srd a concentration check isn't an ability check.