# Can a Strength check made to break something be retried?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

In *Pathfinder* there's a way to break things like doors or walls with sheer brute force. Can a check made to, like, break down such a door be retried?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### A creature that makes a [Strength ability check](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills#TOC-Ability-Checks-and-Caster-Level-Checks1) to [break an object](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/damaging-objects/#TOC-Breaking-Items) and fails *can* typically try to break that object again

Ability checks in *Pathfinder* don't really get a lot of attention. They're largely subsumed into the rules for skills, making it so the reader must extrapolate from the rules for skills the rules for ability checks.

[Ability Checks and Caster Level Checks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills#TOC-Ability-Checks-and-Caster-Level-Checks1) says, "The normal take 10 and take 20 rules apply for ability checks." On [Skill Checks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills#TOC-Skill-Checks1) on Taking 20 says

> When you have plenty of time, you are faced with no threats or distractions, and the skill [or, in this case, the ability check] being attempted carries no penalties for failure, you can take 20. In other words, if you a d20 roll enough times, eventually you will get a 20. Instead of rolling 1d20 for the skill check, just calculate your result as if you had rolled a 20.
>
> Taking 20 means you are trying until you get it right, and it assumes that you fail many times before succeeding. Taking 20 takes 20 times as long as making a single check would take (usually 2 minutes for a skill that takes 1 round or less to perform).
>
> Since taking 20 assumes that your character will fail many times before succeeding, your character would automatically incur any penalties for failure before he or she could complete the task (hence why it is generally not allowed with skills that carry such penalties).…

Thus, if the GM says that the creature *can* do it *20 times*, the creature can, instead, *just* do it a second time… and, presumably, as many times as it likes afterward. So, because a creature *can* typically take 20 on a Strength ability check made to, for example, [bust down a normal door](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/damaging-objects/#TOC-Breaking-Items), a creature that tries and fails on one round to bust down a door can, on the next and later rounds, make *further* attempts to bust down that *same* door. (Note that a creature *can't* take 20 to bust down a door that's, for example, composed of solid flame that deals the creature fire damage each time the creature fails to bust it down: the penalty for failure—the fire damage—makes taking 20 impossible. However, unless the GM forbids it, the creature *could* totally try over and over to bust down that flame door.)

Comment: Although roundabout, this seems like solid evidence

Comment: @Ifusaso I know that it's almost *too* roundabout, but for some reason, *Pathfinder* just totally lacks *3.5e*'s clarity on ability checks. (Also see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/88090/8610).)

Comment: Absolutely agree. From a "this is a game" perspective, I would encourage the GM to treat the STR check more as answering "can the creature break it on the first try?" than "does it get broken?". That is, barring (eg.) the flaming door mentioned, if the strongest character takes 20 and all of the assisting characters' combined STR check would break the door, it's going to get broken; the question is whether it breaks right away or takes a while (and, thus, gives the creatures on the other side time to prepare for the fight, maybe one round per 5 by which the DC was missed?).

Comment: [Related article from The Angry GM](http://theangrygm.com/five-simple-rules-for-dating-my-teenaged-skill-system/) - see rule 3 and the digression. Summarized: let them auto-succeed iff there's no consequence for failure.

Comment: @Riker While I'd summarize that as, instead, *Let them succeed if there's a chance for success **and** no penalty for failure*, yeah, I agree. I mean, there's no *penalty* for trying to use the Knowledge (geography) skill to teleport… but there's usually no chance of success, either!